# error: missing context for method declaration with FB SDK on react native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I thought it would be easy to find similar issue but as fb haven't issues on their github, NO...

I strictly followed the instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

but it leverages this error which clearly indicate that what is after the @end is an issue. I understand that I'm declaring methods outside of the compiler scope but as FB isn't really full of information about this, I don't know what to do.

```
/Users/Jean/dev/mysuperapp/ios/mysuperapp/AppDelegate.m:82:1: error: missing context for method declaration
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
^
/Users/Jean/dev/mysuperapp/ios/mysuperapp/AppDelegate.m:91:1: error: missing context for method declaration
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
^
/Users/Jean/dev/mysuperapp/ios/mysuperapp/AppDelegate.m:106:1: error: missing context for method declaration
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
^
3 errors generated.
```

I've found this similar issue which says that's because the code for FBSDK is after the @end which seems obvious. But if I move the code just before the @end the compiler complains about missing @end...

[Missing context for method declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673499/missing-context-for-method-declaration)

I'm sure it's just about understanding how the compiler works but I'm stuck on this one. I don't know Objective-C at all and I'm very confused with this error.

The entire file:

```
/**
* Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
* All rights reserved.
*
* This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
* LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
* of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
*/

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import "RNFIRMessaging.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;


  #ifdef DEBUG
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #else
  jsCodeLocation = [CodePush bundleURL];
  #endif

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
  moduleName:@"cupido"
  initialProperties:nil
  launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  // Added for FCM
  [FIRApp configure];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];

  return YES;
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging willPresentNotification:notification withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

#if defined(__IPHONE_11_0)
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
#else
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
#endif

//You can skip this method if you don't want to use local notification
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}


@end

//  AppDelegate.m
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
openURL:(NSURL *)url 
options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
  openURL:url
  sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
  annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}

//  AppDelegate.m
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

Comment: @prisoner, there is no such a thing as `Copyright (c) 2015-present` in any country of the world. It should be `2015-2018` instead, because you can't copyright until the end of time.

Comment: @prisonier sorry, but your Objective-C spelling is wrong and without 6 character change it is not approve to change so I added space.

Comment: @ChiragKothiya I think you wanted to reply to me: OK for the 6 characters minimum, I understand. Yet, if you're in a situation where you can't find 6 characters to change, then it may be best to simply leave a comment regarding the typo and someone else will fix it (either the Post Owner or someone with 2000+ reputation). But often, you can find greetings, signature, thank-you, help-me or other optional fluff to remove.

Comment: @Cœur, the copyright is not from me but from facebook code ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the following. I thought I've already did something like this but it appears that I did it wrong. Now my app compiles.

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import "RNFIRMessaging.h" // FCM


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"cupidoIos"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  // Added for FCM
  [FIRApp configure];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];

  return YES;
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging willPresentNotification:notification withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

#if defined(__IPHONE_11_0)
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
#else
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
#endif

//You can skip this method if you don't want to use local notification
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you try like this?:

Code in the instructions should be put between `@implementation AppDelegate` and `@end`.

```
/**
* Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
* All rights reserved.
*
* This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
* LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
* of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
*/

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import "RNFIRMessaging.h"

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;


  #ifdef DEBUG
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #else
  jsCodeLocation = [CodePush bundleURL];
  #endif

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
  moduleName:@"cupido"
  initialProperties:nil
  launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  // Added for FCM
  [FIRApp configure];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging willPresentNotification:notification withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

#if defined(__IPHONE_11_0)
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
#else
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
#endif

//You can skip this method if you don't want to use local notification
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [RNFIRMessaging didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
openURL:(NSURL *)url 
options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
  openURL:url
  sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
  annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

@end
```